# Ubuntu 15.04 suspend freeze

Tags: 15.04, suspend, laptop, acer

I use Ubuntu 15.04 with stock kernel on my laptop.
When I boot up my laptop and then try to suspend, everything works perfectly.
But when I work for few hours and then try to go to suspend, it almost always freezes.

By the look of the LED, it never enters sleep mode. Just black screen.
And I must forcefully shut it down.

I don't even know how to debug this problem. I looked at some log files, but didn't found anything useful to me.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What computer model do you have ?

Comment: It is a Acer laptop, E5-771G.

CPU: Haswell i3 4030u
GPU: Intel 4400 & Nvidia 840m
RAM: 8GB DDR3
SSD: 240GB

Comment: I have the same issue. Asus gaming laptop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that my problem disappeared. I am not sure what happened. Only major thing that is different is the correct installation of NVIDIA drivers. It seems that something with nouveau drivers or nvidia/intel dual gpu system was the problem.